# Sum and divide elements of a RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to sum all the elements of an RDD and then divide it by the number of elements. I was able to solve it but using different lines. However I would like to do it just with a single line using RDD operations.

The RDD is for example:

```
rdd_example = [(eliana,1),(peter,2),(andrew,3),(paul,4),(jhon,5)]
```

The first step is to extract just numbers using the method map with a lambda:

```
numbers = rdd_example.map(lambda x: x[1])
```

The output is:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Then the sum of all the elements, using the method reduce:

```
from operator import add
sum = numbers.reduce(add)
```

Then to count the elements another variable is created, using the method count:

```
number_elem = rdd_example.count()
```

Then a division is done to obtain the result:

```
result = sum/number_elem
```

I would like to do all of it using just a single line, with a single variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fold` with which you can aggregate both the count and sum in one go:

```
cnt, total = rdd_example.fold((0, 0), lambda res, x: (res[0] + 1, res[1] + x[1]))

print(total / cnt)
# 2.5
```

Notice in the call, we use a tuple to store the count and sum:

```
rdd_example.fold((0, 0), lambda res, x: (res[0] + 1, res[1] + x[1]))
#                 ^  ^                   ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                 ^  init sum        add 1 to count / add value to sum
#                 init count
```

Comment: Thank you Psidom I really like your answer, how does the method fold works?

Comment: You can check more explanation on fold here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.fold.html. Basically `fold` takes an initial value and a lambda. The lambda takes the initial value and one element from the rdd, calculates and return a result which will become the new initial value (or aggregate value).

Answer (score 1):

For a single-line solution, observe that you are computing the mean (average) of the numbers. PySpark already has a `mean()` method:

```py
rdd_example = sc.parallelize([("eliana",1),("peter",2),("andrew",3),("paul",4),("jhon",5)])
result = rdd_example.map(lambda x: x[1]).mean()
print(result)
# output: 3.0
```